# Solving a limit by recognizing the sum as a Riemann sum for a function defined on [0,1].

Tags: calculus

[image: Image attached]

I understand that the change in x is represented by $$7/n$$ but how would you go about solving the actual limit here?

Comment: You can put that $7$ out of the limit.

Comment: Forget the $7.$ Perhaps it would help to write it as
$$\sqrt {\frac{1}{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{n} + \sqrt {\frac{2}{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{n}+\cdots + \sqrt {\frac{n}{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$S=7\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}\frac{1}{n}.$$

Let $a=0, b=1$, so that our subintervals have width $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$. Then pick an arbitrary point $x^*_k$ in the $k$-th subinterval. That is, $x^*_k =0 + k\Delta x = \frac{k}{n}$. Also let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, so that $f(x^*_k)$ is the height of each rectangle in the $k$-th subinterval. So $f(x^*_k)\Delta x$ is the area of the $k$-th rectangle. To find the area, we add up many rectangles. That is,
$$S=7\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n f({x^*_k})\Delta x.$$

This is the definition of the area under a curve $f(x)$. So $$S = 7\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: The answer is looking for a number rather than a function. Would I have to plug some number into the x in that equation?

Comment: We transformed the infinite sum into an integral. If you integrate $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$, and multiply by $7$, you'll have the answer.